# How can I modify an existing PDF template? (Zend_Pdf)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am new in Magento,
Right now I am trying to make some modification in the PDF generated in one of my order details page.
I found the app\code\Mypro\RsaDoa\Controller\RSA\PickupLabel.php controller action which is responsible for the Zend Pdf generation and I saw the text content which is present in my pdf there.

I made some change in the text to confirm this is the file, but nothing changed. There are no other similar files, This has to be this one. But why can't I change the contents??

Any idea? Did I miss something? Please help

Comment: Can you share full code of PickupLabel.php?

Comment: Its not about the code.. I tried changing some templated too. None of the changes reflected.  cleared and flushed all caches many times, done deploying.. but still could't find the error

Comment: Yes I understood that but need to check that class for flow. Ignore this request if code is private and can't be shared publicly. But in this case it will be hard to help.

Comment: Sorry I found the issue. Due to some db data issues my local server was redirecting to live. I was changing code in local and looking for that in live. My mistake sorry!